# From emission probability to black body spectrum. (Hawking radiation as tunnelling.)

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, hawking-radiation

In the 1999 paper by Wilczek & Parikh (and in many subsequent papers) the  "emission rate" (really the probability of tunneling) of a particle with energy $\omega$ from a static black hole (BH) is $$\Gamma \sim e^{-\omega/T}$$
The paper recognises this as a Boltzmann factor for the particle and states that following 'Standard arguments' one arrives to the Planck spectral flux
$$\rho(\omega)  \sim \frac{d\omega}{2 \pi} \frac{\omega^3}{e^{-\omega/T}-1}$$

where I have treated the BH as a black body (and didn't bother getting all factors right as it's secondary).

My question is what exactly are these standard arguments? I think this could be answered outside of the context of Hawking radiation as well. I have inkling that it involves putting the BH in a box surrounded by particles and finding equilibrium between emission and absorption.

I include a link to the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9907001.pdf